# Chain rule with change of basis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let us suppose we are given a function $f(x,y)$, which can also be expressed as $g(s,t)$. If we are given either a pair of $x=x(s,t)$ and $y=y(s,t)$, or $s=s(x,y)$ and $t=t(x,t)$, is it possible to use the chain rule to compute the partial derivatives of $g$ in terms of partial derivatives of $f$?

In other words, given that $f(x,y)$ can be expressed as $h(s,t)$, are the following formulas correct?

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}
{\partial s}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$$

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Jacobian (matrix) of a function? The chain rule is particularly simple when stated in terms of the Jacobians.

Comment: @amd I'm afraid I'm not familiar with it, unless you count the minimal understanding I acquired from checking the wikipedia page after reading your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want $f(x,y)=f(x(s,t),y(s,t))$ but thinking to $g$ as change of coordinates $g:\mathbb R^2\cdot\!\!\dashrightarrow\mathbb R^2$, then, for a scalar function
$f:\mathbb R^2\cdot\!\!\dashrightarrow\mathbb R$, 
you can take the composition
$$\mathbb R^2\cdot\!\!\stackrel g\dashrightarrow\mathbb R^2\cdot\!\!\stackrel f\dashrightarrow\mathbb R.$$
So, the Chain's Rule applied to $f\circ g$ gives $(f\circ g)'=f'(g)\cdot g'$ 
and this would be
$$\left[\frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial(f\circ g)}{\partial t}\right]=\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\\
\\
\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\end{array}
\right].
$$
That is
$$\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s},$$
and
$$\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}.$$